# Django mail SMTPlib auth method problem

Tags: django, authentication, smtp

I am trying to send an email using Django and my client's smtp server.
That server supports AUTH LOGIN commands only.

By default (as far as i can see using wireshark) django sends this bit:

```
250-AUTH=LOGIN CRAM-MD5 PLAIN
```

as part of the email message.

I have tracked that to /usr/lib/python/smtplib.py:569 where it chooses the authentication method (there's an option for AUTH_LOGIN which is what i want).

As far as i can see i can't set the auth method using vars in settings.py (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/)

Does anyone know how i can tell Django to use auth_login instead of auth_cram_md5?

Comment: I found this ticket over at Django with a resolution of WONTFIX (!!!): http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9488. Any known workarounds?

Comment: Any workarounds short of using smtplib directly, which i will if it comes to that.

Comment: I am currently struggling with the same problem. Did you find a solution?
During my research I found this page here, without solving my problem: http://www.harelmalka.com/?p=94

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to tell smtplib to use one specific authentication mechanism (credit goes to [SMTP AUTH extension trouble with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6123242/1402076)). The following line of code allows you to suggest authentication mechanisms to smtplib, ignoring other mechanisms offered by the server (e.g. CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5):

```
server.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'LOGIN PLAIN'
```

Another common mistake found on many tutorials is that when using `.starttls()`, one needs to send the `server.ehlo()` twice, once before and once after the `.starttls()`.

Here is the code which worked for me:

```
import smtplib

user = '<username>'
pwd = '<password>'

FROM = 'sender@mail.com'
TO = ['receiver@mail.com']
SUBJECT = 'Testing sending using gmail'
TEXT = 'Testing sending mail using gmail servers'

# Prepare actual message
message = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP("<SMTP-Server-URI>", 25)
    server.set_debuglevel(1) # optional, good for debugging
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'LOGIN PLAIN'
    server.login(user, pwd)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.close()
    print 'successfully sent the mail'
except:
    print 'failed to send mail'
```

This code was only tested with Python 2.7.9 (and not specifically with Django). Hope it helps some people.