# SMTP AUTH extension trouble with Python

Tags: python, email, authentication, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to write a simple Python script to send emails through my company's SMTP server. I am using the following piece of code.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python

import sys,re,os,datetime
from smtplib import SMTP

#Email function
def sendEmail(message):
        sender="SENDERID@COMPANY.com"
        receivers=['REVEIVER1@COMPANY.com','RECEIVER2@COMPANY.com']
        subject="Daily Report - " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %y")
        header="""\
                From: %s
                To: %s
                Subject: %s

                %s""" % (sender, ", ".join(receivers), subject, message)
        smtp = SMTP()
        smtp.set_debuglevel(1)
        smtp.connect('X.X.X.X')
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()
        try:
                smtp.login('SENDERID@COMPANY.com', '********')
                smtp.sendmail(sender,receivers,header)
                smtp.quit()
        except Exception, e:
                print e

#MAIN
sendEmail("HAHHAHAHAHAH!!!")
```

Running this program, yields this result.

```
connect: ('X.X.X.X', 25)
connect: ('X.X.X.X', 25)
reply: '220 COMPANY.com [ESMTP Server] service ready;ESMTP Server; 05/25/11 15:59:27\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: COMPANY.com [ESMTP Server] service ready;ESMTP Server; 05/25/11 15:59:27
connect: COMPANY.com [ESMTP Server] service ready;ESMTP Server; 05/25/11 15:59:27
send: 'ehlo SERVER1.COMPANY.com\r\n'
reply: '250-COMPANY.com\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 15728640\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250 STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: COMPANY.com
SIZE 15728640
8BITMIME
STARTTLS
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '220 Ready to start TLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: Ready to start TLS
send: 'ehlo SERVER2.COMPANY.com\r\n'
reply: '250-COMPANY.com\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 15728640\r\n'
reply: '250 8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: COMPANY.com
SIZE 15728640
8BITMIME
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: '221 [ESMTP Server] service closing transmission channel\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: [ESMTP Server] service closing transmission channel
ERROR: Could not send email! Check the reason below.
SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

How do I start debugging this "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server." error?

P.S.: I know the SMTP details and credentials are correct, as I have a working Java class with the exact details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you get means the SMTP server you're talking to doesn't claim to support authentication. If you look at the debug output you'll see that none of the responses to your `EHLO`s contain the necessary declaration for `AUTH`. If it did (properly) support authentication, one of the responses would be something like:

```
250 AUTH GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN
```

(at least in reponse to the `EHLO` after the `STARTTLS`.) Because that response isn't included, smtplib assumes the server won't be able to handle the `AUTH` command, and will refuse to send it. If you're certain your SMTP server does support the `AUTH` command even though it doesn't advertise it, you *can* sneakily convince smtplib that it supports `AUTH` by explicitly adding it to the set of features. You'll need to know which kind of authentication schemes are supported, and then you can do:

```
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
# Pretend the SMTP server supports some forms of authentication.
smtp.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'LOGIN DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN'
```

... but of course making the SMTP server behave according to spec would be a better idea :)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Can you give me a list of all possible authentication methods, so I can try each one?

Comment: There isn't really a complete list, but Python only supports `CRAM-MD5`, `PLAIN` and `LOGIN`, so there's no point in trying others.

Comment: I tried all 3, didn't work. Finally I found this SMTP wrapper (http://ginstrom.com/code/mailer.html) that works like a charm. Will have to dig into the code to figure out what I was doing wrong!

Comment: It sounds like the SMTP server simply doesn't support authentication. Did you consider removing the login call?

Comment: That did it! So does that mean our SMTP server is insecure?

Comment: No, it means it doesn't require authentication. Whether it's insecure depends on how it uses TLS and where it accepts connections from.

Comment: Having auth can limit users to send email only using their username, other than that. The server is not insecure in the sense that smtp protocol is a protocol that highly rely on trust. You could for example allow sending mails only if the connection come from the server itself and receive any mail but refuse to relay it if it's not your own domain. In other words, auth isn't that really important in some case.