# Sending an Email with Python Issue

Tags: python, email

I have this code and I cannot seem to get it to work.  When I run it, the script doesn't finish in IDLE unless I kill it manually.  I have looked all over and rewritten the code a few times, and no luck.

```
import smtplib

SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 587

sender = 'abc@gmail.com'
password = '123'
recipient = 'cba@gmail.com'
subject = 'Test Results'
body = """** AUTOMATED EMAIL ** \r\n Following are
            the test results:  \r\n"""

headers = ["From: " + sender,
           "Subject: " + subject,
           "To: " + recipient]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

try:
      session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
      session.ehlo()
      session.starttls()
      session.ehlo()
      session.login(sender, password)
      session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
except smtplib.SMTPException:
      print "Error: Unable to send email."

session.quit()
```

Comment: Are there any error logs you could check to see what is happening at the point where the script gets stuck?

Comment: Try changing your ```except``` line to ```except smtplib.SMTPException as e:``` then print ```e```

Comment: @wnnmaw I tried that, but the same thing happens, the cursor just blinks and the script doesn't finish, I have to kill it manually.

Comment: @summea I don't know how to check the error logs...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're using `ehlo`; contrary to popular opinion, it's not actually required so long as you set the headers correctly. Here's a tested and working script -- it works on *nix and OSX. Since you're using Windows though, we need to troubleshoot further.

```
import smtplib, sys

def notify(fromname, fromemail, toname, toemail, subject, body, password):
    fromaddr = fromname+" <"+fromemail+">"
    toaddrs = [toname+" <"+toemail+">"]
    msg = "From: "+fromaddr+"\nTo: "+toemail+"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: text/plain\nSubject: "+subject+"\n"+body

    # Credentials (if needed)
    username = fromemail
    password = password

    # The actual mail send
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username,password)
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
        server.quit()       
        print "success"
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        print "failure"

fromname = "Your Name"
fromemail = "yourgmailaccount@gmail.com"        
toname = "Recipient"
toemail = "recipient@other.com"
subject = "Test Mail"
body = "Body....."

notify(fromname, fromemail, toname, toemail, subject, body, password)
```

Comment: I copied this script and changed the fromname etc. and added in password, but the same thing is still happening to me. It runs but the cursor just flashes and it doesn't finish unless I kill it.

Comment: That's definitely a send mail problem. See if you can successfully send mail from the command line using `sendmail`? Next step is toe check the logs.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you are talking about. I opened cmd.exe and typed sendmail and it said it is not recognized...

Comment: Oh, Windows is a different story. You won't have sendmail to test with. Also I wrote this wrong: change the `except SMTPException:` to `except smtplib.SMTPException:`. Try purposefully mistyping the smtp url to see if it's correctly handling errors (e.g. `smtpa.gmail.com:587`).

Comment: When I type smtpa.gmail.com:587 I do get errors with the smtplib.py file.  With the other change you had included, nothing different happened.

Comment: Plot thickens! Are you able to test it on another machine? Perhaps a linux box?

Comment: I don't have access to a linux machine. I will however test it on my personal machine later today and update accordingly. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I was able to run the script you provided as well as the one that I had written originally at home on my Mac.  They both work.  I am wondering if there is something else I need to provide to get through at work?

Comment: Wondering if it's the fact that it's Windows that's causing the problem? Somehow you need to find the Windows smtplib logs. Can you use PrtQryUI to make sure you can access the google server on 587?

Comment: From what I understand from PortQry I ran the command: portqry -n smtp.gmail.com -p tcp -e 25.  It resolves the name to an IP address, and then an error.  I get: Error opening socket: 10013 A Winsock error has occured.

Comment: That error is a permission denied error. Am I not being let out of my work network?

Comment: No, it's blocking 25. Try with 587 instead

Comment: I tried 587 and same error.  I tried 465 and I get a listening result, but when I use it in place of 587 in the script, same result as before.

Comment: Then I think something's blocking it, either Windows firewall or some other client software (McAfee, Symantec, et al).

Comment: Okay I will play around and see what I can do.

Comment: I turned off the McAfee as well as the firewall and no luck.

Comment: Yeah everything else I can find on the issue sounds like I am being block by the ISP.

Comment: Quite possibly, yeah - might contact them.

Comment: It looks like there are messaging gateways, and I cannot contact gmail directly.  With debuglevel set to 1 I am actually getting some send and reply, however I am still failing.

Comment: I guess another way to check - do you have locally installed IMAP/smtp client (Windows Mail, Outlook) that you could connect to gmail? If so, can you send?

Comment: I don't all of our email is connected to from our home page. I have it on my phone, but it doesnt have a box for SMPT outgoing mail server like my personal accounts do.

Comment: Finally got it all figured out.  Once I used the work mailhost I was getting this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123072/smtp-auth-extension-trouble-with-python) but was able to solve it by removing the login requirement from the script.  Thanks for all your help, I learned quite a bit during this.

Comment: Ah fantastic! Be aware that if you're using a different SMTP server you might have mail flagged as spam.

Comment: Yeah I believe it is taken care of by the gateways that forward the message past the anti-spam systems.  I was able to send it to myself a few times.

Comment: It's on the recipient side you have to worry about -- "you@gmail.com" probably isn't trusted on a lot of mail servers if it's coming from your company's own servers.

Comment: Yeah our email is gmail hosted but its not me@gmail.com its me@company.com and the emails will be within the company, so I think it should be okay...