# python email sending script gmail

Tags: python, email

I am making a simple script for send mail through gmail account in python 2.7.5.. Before send mail i wanna check that whether user successfully login through gmail smtp or not... Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
user = raw_input("Enter Your email address: ")
password= raw_input("Enter your email password: ")
receipt = raw_input("Enter Receipt email address: ")
subject = raw_input ("Subject: ")
msg = raw_input("Message: ")
message =  """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
            """ % (user, ", ".join(receipt), subject, msg)
smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port = 587
session = smtplib.SMTP()
session.connect(smtp_host, smtp_port)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo
print "Connecting to the server....."
try:
    session.login(user, password) 
    if (session.verify(True)):
        print "Connected to the server. Now sending mail...."
        session.sendmail(user, receipt, message)
        session.quit()
        print "Mail have been sent successfully.....!"
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print "Can not connected to the Server...!"

print "Simple mail Test"
```

But when i run it, then it will give "Can not Connected to the Server". can any body help me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know whether it's relevant, but you're missing parentheses from the second `session.ehlo`.

Comment: when you debug your code, how far do you get, where does the exception occur?

Comment: did you watch the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008030/sending-an-email-with-python-issue?rq=1? looks quite similar to me

Comment: drop the `try` and `except` and post the full stack trace.

Comment: RichieHindle >> I had used session.ehlo ... check the question again...  Zaiborg >> Sir when i debug it then it will give can not connected to the server.... check my question again.... WeaselFox >> If i will drop the try except then how i can able to know that whether user connected with smtp or not?

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot a couple of things. The receipt have to be a list, and the verify method take the user email as argument. Here's the code with some improvements:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
receipt,cc_list=[],[]
user = raw_input("Enter Your email address: ")
password= raw_input("Enter your email password: ")
receipt.append(raw_input("Enter Receipt email address: "))
subject = raw_input ("Subject: ")
message = raw_input("Message: ")

header  = 'From: %s\n' % user
header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(receipt)
header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_list)
header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
message = header + message

smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port = 587
session = smtplib.SMTP()
session.connect(smtp_host, smtp_port)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo

print "Connecting to the server....."
try:
    session.login(user, password) 
    if (session.verify(user)):
        print "Connected to the server. Now sending mail...."
        session.sendmail(user, receipt, message)
        session.quit()
        print "Mail have been sent successfully.....!"
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print "Can not connected to the Server...!"

print "Simple mail Test"
```

Comment: No sir same problem... it will give result that "Can not connected to the server.....!" .... My question is very simple that.... i am using all code in right way... no depend one or more then one receipt here.... problem is that ... why it the my email and pass can't login in smtp ? ... i have tried with different email address too ... but same problem